# mascara de dados com php

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo, ckeditor

estou tentando sem sucesso substituir os valores retornado de um campo do banco de dados, que retorna um codigo html do ckeditor.

estou tentando fazer dessa forma:

```
$class = new Selecionar();
    $class->setProcesso($processo);
    $class->setTitulo($anexo);
    $class->setUserid($userid);
    $dados = $class->getAnexosByProcesso();

    function str_replace_string($search, $replace, $subject) {
        return str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
    }

    $mask = array('%NOME%', '%EMAIL%', '%CPF%', '%RG%', '%TELEFONE%', '%RUA%', '%NUMERO%', '%BAIRRO%', '%CIDADE%', '%ESTADO%', '%CEP%', '%OBJETO%');

    $values = array($dados['nome'], $dados['email'], $dados['cpf'], $dados['rg'], $dados['telefone'], $dados['rua'], $dados['numero'], $dados['bairro'], $dados['cidade'], $dados['uf'], $dados['cep'], $dados['objeto']);

    $resultado = str_replace_string($mask[0], $values[0], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[1], $values[1], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[2], $values[2], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[3], $values[3], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[4], $values[4], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[5], $values[5], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[6], $values[6], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[7], $values[7], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[8], $values[8], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[9], $values[9], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[10], $values[10], $dados['modelo']);
    $resultado .= str_replace_string($mask[11], $values[11], $dados['modelo']);

    echo $resultado;
```

Eu preciso que ele me substitua o indice correspondente dos 2 arrays demonstrados acima ($mask e $values), quero substituir as mascaras do $mask pelo valor do $values simultaneamente, já tentei usar for e foreach sem sucesso, tentei com fetchAll() no sql também sem sucesso.

Do jeito que está ele me retorna apenas o primeiro valor, quando utilizo foreach ele me retorna o ultimo valor, alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```
function str_replace_string($search, $replace, $subject) {
        return str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
    }

    $mask = array('%NOME%', '%EMAIL%', '%CPF%', '%RG%', '%TELEFONE%', '%RUA%', '%NUMERO%', '%BAIRRO%', '%CIDADE%', '%ESTADO%', '%CEP%', '%OBJETO%');

    $values = array($dados['nome'], $dados['email'], $dados['cpf'], $dados['rg'], $dados['telefone'], $dados['rua'], $dados['numero'], $dados['bairro'], $dados['cidade'], $dados['uf'], $dados['cep'], $dados['objeto']);
//    $resultado = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mask); $i++) {
        $resultado = str_replace_string($mask, $values, $dados['modelo']);

    }

     echo $resultado;
```

fiz o loop e o erro era que eu estava indexando as variaveis, nesse caso ela estava quebrando as strings de cada indice, o que fiz foi tirar os [$i] dos arrays, agora recebo todos os valores substituidos.